# submitted django form properly contains user data but shows as unbound and invalid

Tags: django, forms

I have a form with a single ChoiceField (widget radioselect) whose choices are dynamically generated and render perfectly. When the form is submitted the POST data shows the correct value (1-5) for the choice selected (in live debug and in the browser debug info) but for whatever reason the form is considered unbound and invalid. Here's the form:

```
class ReValidateStudentForm(forms.Form):
    bs_answer = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, label='Answer', required=True)

    def __init__(self, possible_answers, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReValidateStudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bs_answer'].choices = possible_answers
```

FYI, "possible_answers" is a list of tuples passed to the form that is presenting perfectly as radio select choices when the fresh form is rendered. request.method does equal POST.

Any advice?

***EDIT***

Here's the form view code:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def ask_identity_questions(request):
    si = StudentInfo.objects.get(student=request.user)
    qnum = si.bs_question_number
    if request.method == 'POST':
        revalidateform = ReValidateStudentForm(request.POST)
        try:
            va = VerificationAnswers.objects.get(student=request.user, question_num=qnum)
        except VerificationAnswers.DoesNotExist:
            return render(request, "informational.html", {'message': 'User--question does not exist.'})
        if revalidateform.is_valid():
            va.student = request.user
            va.question_num = si.bs_question_number
            va.answer_choice = revalidateform.cleaned_data['bs_answer']
            va.question_answered_time = timezone.now()
            si.bs_question_number += 1
            si.save()
            return render(request, "informational.html", {'message': 'Thank you! Please <a href="/toc">click here </a> to continue working through the course material.'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'questions.html', {'form': revalidateform, 'question_num': qnum, 'question': va.question_text})
    else:
        if qnum == 6:
            return render(request, "informational.html", {'message': 'You have already answered all validation questions.'})
        elif si.bs_qset_id == '':
            return render(request, "informational.html", {'message': 'There is a problem with your identity validation information. Please contact customer support.'})
        else:
            # initialize blockscore account
            client = blockscore.Client({'api_key':'sk_live_149dthis3ddiseb2f5notbebforebreal'})
            si = StudentInfo.objects.get(student=request.user)
            # set question ask time
            # retrieve the user's question set using question set id stored in StudentInfo
            # retrieve specific question from set based on value in StudentInfo
            qset = client.question_sets.retrieve(si.bs_qset_id)
            qset = qset.body
            question = qset["questions"][qnum - 1].get("question")
            # add verification question and mark time asked
            try:
                va = VerificationAnswers.objects.get(student=request.user, question_num=qnum)
            except VerificationAnswers.DoesNotExist:
                va = VerificationAnswers()
                va.student = request.user
                va.question_num = qnum
                va.question_text = question
                va.question_asked_time = timezone.now()
                va.save()
            # create answer list
            possible_answers = []
            # fill answer list with tuples of answer ids + answers
            for answer in qset["questions"][qnum - 1].get("answers"):
                possible_answers.append((answer.get("id"), answer.get("answer")))
            revalidateform = ReValidateStudentForm(possible_answers)
            return render(request, 'questions.html', {'form': revalidateform, 'question_num': qnum, 'question': question})
```

Comment: We need to see the form view code, as that is where your problem most likely is.

Comment: Ok, no problem. But remember that the form renders fine, the field value shows up fine in POST data and the .is_valid is one of the first lines to run.